# Jssor Slider how to add arrows to thumbnail image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

I am trying to use this image gallery:

http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html

How can I add left and right arrows navigation to the thumbnail slider above the same like this demo:

http://www.jssor.com/demos/thumbnail-navigator-with-arrows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thumbnail navigator is also a kind of slider, you can add arrow navigator for thumbnail navigator.

```
var options = {
    ...,
    $Align: 360,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
    $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
        ...,

        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
            $ChanceToShow: 2,
            $Steps: 6                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        }
    }
};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);


<!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin Begin -->
<div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 100px; left:0px; bottom: 0px;">
    <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
    <style>
        /* thumbnail css here */
    </style>
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
        <div u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 72px; height: 72px; top: 0; left: 0;">
            <div class=w><div u="thumbnailtemplate" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div></div>
            <div class=c>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->

    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <style>
        /* arrow css here */
    </style>
    <!-- Arrow Left -->
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora11l" style="width: 37px; height: 37px; top: 123px; left: 8px;">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora11r" style="width: 37px; height: 37px; top: 123px; right: 8px">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->

</div>
<!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
```

See this demo http://www.jssor.com/testcase/image-gallery.source.html

**Edit:**

You can adjust $Align value to set offset position of thumbnails.

Github repository: https://github.com/jssor/slider

The '$' in the js code is kind of mark for compression.

Comment: A++. Perfect. I hope you add this as an official demo with your packages. One more issue if you do not mind, how to make the left and right half images in the thumbnail slider as a full images. Last thing, I'd recommend this nice and big project to post it on github for others to share and participate and make it better popular, also I'd recommend make each demo in a folder and each demo has a css file for the theme/skin because it is currently very messy and confusing specially the class names, I wish also to remove the $ dollar sign from the JS code functions and variables will be better.

Comment: Thank you, glad for the github link. What difference between the jssor.slider.mini.js and jssor.slider.min.js files

Comment: Both are fully workable version, you can use either. jssor.slider.min.js  reserves some basic api to use without jquery. So, the size of jssor.slider.min.js is larger.